# how to fix attribute value type error for tags in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform0.12+

I'm getting below attribute error while trying to upgrade the  terraform code from 0.11 to 0.12.29.

Could anyone please help me on resolving the below error.

Error:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on ../../asg.tf line 68, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "asg":
  68:   tags = concat( 

Inappropriate value for attribute "tags": element 18: map of string required.
```

0.11 code:

```
tags = ["${concat( 
    list(
      map("key", "Name", "value", "${lookup(var.common, "Name")}", "propagate_at_launch", true),
      map("key", "Project", "value", "${lookup(var.common, "project")}", "propagate_at_launch", true)
      ),
    var.asgcustomtags)
}"]
```

0.12 code:

```
tags = concat( 
    [
      {"key" = "Name", "value" = "${lookup(var.common, "Name")}", "propagate_at_launch" = true},
      {"key" = "Project", "value" = "${lookup(var.common, "project")}", "propagate_at_launch" = true},
    ],
    var.asgcustomtags,
  )
```

Thank you in advance.